flask-caching config ignores the redis password
Hey I do not understand why flask-caching seems to be ignoring the redis password
I have a redis setup with a password set to 1234, but when I configure flask-caching with a config using a CACHE_REDIS_PASSWORD also set to 1234, I am still getting the "Authentication Required" error
i put this in my redis-cli
CONFIG SET requirepass 1234

when i unset my password it works just fine (actually it shouldnt. when providing a password for a redis instance that doesnt have a password, it should show a warning, or fail)
CONFIG SET requirepass ""

I am using flask_caching version 2.3.0 and redis 4.5.4 with flask 2.2.5
a minimal setup would be
from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache

app = Flask(__name__)
config = {
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache', 'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'resources_cache ',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': f'redis://localhost:6379/0', 'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 5,
    'CACHE_REDIS_PASSWORD': 1234
}

cache = Cache(app=app, config=config)
cache.clear()

and the authentication error happens at cache.clear()
redis.exceptions.AuthenticationError: Authentication required.

Are there any obvious problems with this, or a possible version conflict?
needless to say I would not actually use the password 1234, this is just a test to see if any password works

Indeed flask-caching is the faulty library here for the version number of 2.3.0. Looks like when it's creating a redis instance from the url, it fails to account for the passed-in password to the redis url.
It's creating a redis instance from the default url of redis://localhost:6379/0 instead of redis://:<password>@localhost:6379/0.
You can see the bug here on line 87 during the instance creation through the factory method of the responsible cache backend:
...
    kwargs["host"] = redis_from_url(redis_url, db=kwargs.pop("db", None))
...

cachelib is working fine if you don't want to rely on flask-caching here and its api is very well simple. On the other hand, you have to file a bug report and wait for an update for the latter.

great, this is good, i was really questioning if I did something wrong here, I couldn't figure it out. Do you have any idea if an earlier version would work correctly? The line you highlighted (although I dont really understand why it causes the bug) seems unchanged from earlier versions. Did that really just never work? Could I maybe specify the CACHE_REDIS_URL specifically and put the password there instead? Or leave it blank? I can't really believe nobody has figured this out or made a bugreport yet...

Wait, I totally missed that you were using a URL indeed. Okay that makes sense now. You need to include the password in the url. That's what urls are for. Therefore I wouldn't say the library has a bug, you need to pass in the correct url. Maybe we can create a bug report, but I don't think what you did classifies as a bug.

See my answer, I dont think it's logical or intuitive that the cache can be configured to use a url and password, but the password is ignored if you use an url. there should at least be a warning that if you use the url, the parameters that are part of the url are ignored (this concerns all the parameters DB, PORT, URL, PASSWORD), the url simply overwrites them all. It's debatable if it's a bug, but the issue can be addressed

Thanks to BcK's answer, I was able to deduce what's happening:
Turns out you should not use the parameter CACHE_REDIS_PASSWORD in conjunction with CACHE_REDIS_URL because the latter will simply overwrite any password you defined earlier, and use the URL as a connection string directly. I am not sure if this is intended, but it seems unintuitive and is not documented well.
Therefore, defining the url separately in parts using
    "CACHE_REDIS_HOST": "localhost",
    "CACHE_REDIS_PORT": "6379",
    "CACHE_REDIS_PASSWORD": "1234",

in the config like this works as expected (because the parameter CACHE_REDIS_URL will be None, and therefore ignored).
But if you also use CACHE_REDIS_URL at the same time, ONLY the URL will be used and all the other parameters that are part of the url will be ignored.
Alternatively, you can also define the password in the URL like this:
    "CACHE_REDIS_URL": "redis://:1234@localhost:6379/0"

without defining the password separately (this also applies to PORT, DB and HOST, because they are all part of the URL, which takes precedence when defined. The URL is One Parameter to rule them all)
